# How to Start an Activity and Call a Method from Another Class on Click in a Jetpack Glance Widget?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, glance-appwidget, glance

I'm working on an Android app where I'm using Jetpack Glance for creating a widget. I need to implement functionality where a click on the widget's button starts an activity and also calls a method from another class. However, I'm unsure how to correctly implement this, as my current approach only allows for a single action.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// Example of my current Glance widget implementation
@Composable
fun MyGlanceWidget() {
    // ...
    Box(
        modifier = GlanceModifier.clickable(
            actionStartActivity(Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java))
        )
    )
    // ...
}

// The method I want to call from another class
class AnalyticsTracker {
    fun trackWidgetClick() {
        // Tracking logic
    }
}
```

In this setup, clicking the box starts `MyActivity`, but I also need to execute `trackWidgetClick()` from `AnalyticsTracker` class. I'm unsure how to modify my Glance widget to accommodate both actions on a single click.

Could someone provide guidance or an example of how to achieve this in a Jetpack Glance widget?

Comment: It looks like a limitation with the current API, you can only do one action. I suppose this isn't technically true for a lambda action, but you can't start an activity there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an action and maybe even some extras on the Intent:

```
actionStartActivity(
    Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
        .setAction("startedFromWidget")
        .putExtra("param1", false)
)
```

then you get those in your activity and do whatever you need:

```
class MyActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        checkIntent(intent)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        ...
        checkIntent(intent)
    }

    private fun checkIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == "startedFromWidget") {
            val param = intent.getBooleanExtra("param1", false)
            trackWidgetClick(param)
        }
        // set activity.intent to null so you don't check it again
        // when activity is recreated
        this.intent = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, But I want a solution for the general use-case which is what can we do if we want to start an activity and also do another operation. With current actions is not somehow possible, For example, we can not start Activity from LambdaAction and CallbackAction due to some limitations.

Comment: Then provide a better example that actually shows what you are not able to do... Widgets are kinda limited, so don't expect you can do the same things you can do in normal UI. I don't understand what you mean by "start Activity from LambdaAction and CallbackAction", can you provide an example?

Comment: I point out it in the question title: "How to Start an Activity and Call a Method from Another Class on Click in a Jetpack Glance Widget"
Tracking scenario is just an example, imagine I want to open an activity and also want to call a fun that could be anything.
With current Actions in glance I could not find a way to achieve this, we can only use `actionStartActivity` for starting activity but it's limited to one action and in the other actions in Glance(Lambda and Callback) we can not start activity.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/glance/user-interaction#run-actioncallback

Comment: Well like I said, widgets are limited, you cannot do everything the same way you would in your normal UI. I provided the workaround that works and you can do pretty much anything with it. If there is something that is not possible to do like that, provide example. If it's just about that you don't like the way it's done, you gotta deal with it I guess...